# What gradle task pulls dependencies from remote repositories?

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I am making the switch to Gradle for my Android project. I have imported the project into Android Studio from Eclipse and have wrapped it using Gradle 1.8.

My assumption was Gradle handled dependencies the way as Maven, that is if you specify a dependency that does not exist in your local repository it will pull it from the remote repository. Android Studio is not pulling in my dependencies. I attempted to run `./gradlew androidDependencies --debug` but I do not see any downloading of the dependencies however they are being acknowledged they are there and no warnings/errors are thrown.

```
11:11:36.833 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.CachingModuleVersionRepository] Using cached module metadata for module 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader#parent;1.8.6' in 'MavenRepo'
11:11:36.834 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.UserResolverChain] Using module 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:parent:1.8.6' from repository 'MavenRepo'
11:11:36.855 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DependencyGraphBuilder] Visiting configuration com.nostra13.universalimageloader:parent:1.8.6(default).
11:11:36.857 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DependencyGraphBuilder] Attaching com.nostra13.universalimageloader:parent:1.8.6(default) to its parents.
```

Gradle does take the dependency and create metadata from it in this location

```
/home/wil/.gradle/caches/artifacts-26/filestore/com.nostra13.universalimageloader/parent/1.8.6/pom/41669498c2bec505b61772b083cab341653cb86b
```

Interestingly I have found that if I have the maven dependencies locally it will pull it into Android Studio as an External Library and it will also add the jar to the gradle cache filestore it will just not do this for remote dependencies I specifiy.

Here is my build.gradle

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.3'
}
}
repositories{
    mavenCentral()
}
apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:parent:1.8.6'
}

android {
compileSdkVersion 19
buildToolsVersion "19"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 17
}
sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
    }
    instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
    debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
    release.setRoot('build-types/release')
}
}
```

I am running Android Studio 0.3.6, Ubuntu 13.04, Gradle 1.8, JDK 6

What gradle command should I run that should pull down remote dependencies from a maven repository? Am I missing a configuration setting somewhere that allows downloading of dependencies?

Comment: Remote dependencies are downloaded automatically as soon as a task needs them. There is no task for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remote dependencies are downloaded automatically as soon as a task needs them. If you, for example, compile your project's code, compile dependencies will be downloaded, unless they already exist in Gradle's dependency cache. Out of the box, Gradle doesn't come with a task that merely downloads all dependencies without doing anything with them, but it would be easy to write one.

Comment: That's not happening when I run Build->Compile in Android Studio. It fails saying `Gradle: package com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core does not exist`. Any suggestions for debugging why they are not fetched?

Comment: First thing to check is if it works with plain command-line Gradle. The `parent` artifact ID is suspicious; usually this is the name for a module that's used as the parent of another module, and the build would depend on that other module. Adding everything together, that's likely the cause of your problem.

Comment: Seriously you have no idea how much of a headache this was giving me, I thought the parent id was weird too, upon further inspection in the repo I found a sub module and tried that and it downloaded as expected. Thank you very much!

Comment: Parent modules only have a POM but no main artifact (i.e. Jar). This explains what you were seeing.

Answer (score 4):

By using `gradle dependencies` command line, you can pull down all everything specified in your build.gradle